# Ruby on Rails :How can constants availables to my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
module ConstantModelName
  AIRPORT =  "Airport"
end
```

This module is in lib folder of my app.
I want avialble this constant(AIRPORT) value to my views. 
Is this possible? If Yes, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use ConstantModelName::AIRPORT in your views.